# Convert Accents to raw data SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, blob, diacritics

I have a column( BLOB data) in which accents are used. I would like to search for all the rows have a particular accent( not all the accents and replace them, a particular one).

Suppose I want to search `l'application Data`

I have used below query but it does not work.

```
select * 
from "correspondence" s
where dbms_lob.instr(s."__data", utl_raw.cast_to_raw('l'application Data')) > 0 
and "externalReferenceNumber"like' 20160929%' 
and "callingapplication"=' CVM'  
and rownum < 5
order by s."__id" desc ;
```

Could you please help? It seems by using below also it does not work.

```
utl_raw.cast_to_raw('l || char(146) ||application Data')
```

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: No Row is returned.  If I remove "1" and  the grave symbol ' after 1 , then the result is correct. Thus SQl dev is unable to convert char(146) to grave symbol or varchar2

Answer (score 1):

You need two `'` in a row if you want one as part of your literal

```
 utl_raw.cast_to_raw('l''application Data')
```

oracle also has a wacky syntax for alternate quotes like this

```
 utl_raw.cast_to_raw(q'!l'application Data!')
```

The character after `q'` can be anything as long as it is matched at the end and if you use [, <, (, or { it will match with the "correct" ending }, ), > or ]

see more here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i42617

> The syntax highlighting on SO seems to be mystified by the alternative 2nd syntax :)

Comment: Hi Hogan. I have tried this but it will not work as the symbol " ' " is not a apostrophe but a grave assent symbol used in french language.

Comment: @SombudhyaBasu - if you want to use an extended character set you need to prefix with `N`

Comment: Hi Hogan,  
utl_raw.cast_to_raw(N''l’application Data')
This query gives me the error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: @SombudhyaBasu - hard to tell but it looks to me like you are using a double quote `"` and not a single quote `'`